# Sum of figures inside iteration - rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, loops, sum

I have four teams, each with four individuals, I'm trying to create a chart for each team, `@all` selects each individual from the team and groups by the team id, so this loop would produce 4 iterations, I'm trying to sum the target, forecast and achieved figures for each team with this:

```
<% @all.each do |a| %>

<div style="width:100%; height: 900px; overflow: auto;">
<br>
<h1>
    <%= Date.today.strftime("%B")  %>
    Sales : <%= a.team.name %>
</h1>

<canvas id="<%= a.team.name %>" height="800" width="1000"></canvas>

<% @main = Individual.find(:all, :conditions => "team_id = '#{a.team_id}'")%>


<script>
    var target = <%= @main.sum(:target) %>;
    var forecast = <%= @main.sum(:forecast) %>;
    var achieved = <%= @main.sum(:achieved) %>;
    var barChartData = {
        labels : ["Target", "Forecast", "Achieved"],
        datasets : [{
            fillColor : "rgba(237,28,36,1)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(237,28,36,1)",
            data : [target, forecast, achieved]
        }]

    }
    var opt = {
        scaleFontFamily : "'Trebuchet'",
        scaleFontSize : 20,
        scaleFontColor : "#fff",

    }

    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("<%= a.team.name %>").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData, opt);

</script>

</div>
<% end %>
```

but I get this error `undefined method '+' for #<Individual:0x007ff08c8164e0>`

if i run through each individual separately it shows the correct figures, just won't sum them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass procs not symbols, for instance, replace:

```
@main.sum(:target)
```

with

```
@main.sum(&:target)
```

to consider nil values as 0:

```
@main.sum { |el| el.target.to_f } # use to_f or to_i depending on your data
```

---

Side note, consider using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to pass data in js.

Comment: then I get this... `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`

Comment: ok so you've nil values sometimes... is it normal you dont have numeric on these fields?

Comment: not a problem, I've changed the nil values to zero and now it works, once they're zero they'll never be changed back to nil again so this should be fine! Thanks